# how to split this bit?

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation

it is possible split it:

```
int n = 1 | 2;
```

to

```
int a = n ?? // returns 1
int b = n ?? // returns 2
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? Your question is unclear. `int n = 1|2;` is exactly equivalent to `int n = 3;`. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can use:

```
int a = n & 1;
int b = n & 2;
```

That's fine if 1 and 2 are the only values which are going to be OR-ed together... but it's not really clear whether that's the case. You haven't shown what other values `n` might have.

Answer (score 3):

```
int n = ...;
int a = n & 1; // returns 1 or 0
int b = n & 2; // returns 2 or 0
```